# Prove that if $\mathcal{F}[x_d]\subseteq \mathcal{G}$, then there's a subnet $(y_e)$ of $(x_d)$ such that $\mathcal{G}=\mathcal{F}[y_e]$.

Tags: general-topology, filters, nets

Let $X$ be a set.

Given any net $(x_d)_{d\in D}$ in $X$, we define

$$\color{red}{\mathcal{F}[x_d]}:=\big\{F\in 2^X:(\exists d_0\in D)(\forall d\in D)\big(d_0\preceq _Dd\Rightarrow x_d\in F\big)\big\}.$$

It's easy to prove that $\mathcal{F}[x_d]$ is a filter on $X$.

---

**My question is:** Prove that if $\mathcal{G}$ is a filter on $X$ such that $\mathcal{F}[x_d]\subseteq \mathcal{G}$, then there's a subnet $(y_e)_{e\in E}$ of $(x_d)_{d\in D}$ such that $\mathcal{G}=\mathcal{F}[y_e]$.

---

I'm using the following definition of subnet.

> We say that $(y_e)_{e\in E}$ is a **subnet** of $(x_d)_{d\in D}$ is
> there's a map $\kappa :E\to D$ such that
>
> 1. $y_e=x_{\kappa(e)}$ for all $e\in E$
> 2. $\kappa (e_1)\preceq_D\kappa(e_2)$ for any $e_1,e_2\in E$ with $e_1\preceq _Ee_2$;
> 3. For all $d\in D$ there's $e\in E$ such that $d\preceq _D\kappa (e)$

---

I tried a standard approach to construct a subnet of $(x_d)_{d\in D}$. That is, first I tried to find a proposition $\phi $ such that $E:=\{(d,F)\in D\times \mathcal{G}:\phi \}$ is a directed set with the relation $\preceq_E $ given by: $(d_1,F_1)\preceq _E(d_2,F_2)$ if and only if $d_1\preceq _Dd_2$ and $F_2\subseteq F_1$. Then define $\kappa :E\to D$ by $\kappa (d,F):=d$ and $y:E\to X,\,e\mapsto y_e$  by $y_e:=x_{\kappa(e)}$.

However I didn't find a convenient proposition $\phi$ such that $\mathcal{G}=\mathcal{F}[y_e]$.

---

Thank you for your attention

Comment: Where did you see this claim?

Comment: Unless you allow the empty net this result is false. Take G to be the entire power set of X.

Comment: @FShrike I saw that proposition in the page 13 of the PDF [Nets and filters (are better than sequences)](http://www.math.toronto.edu/ivan/mat327/docs/other/nets.pdf). Also, the entire power set isn't a filter since it contains the empty set.

Comment: Then you should ask for a “proper” filter. I guess convention varies on this

Comment: this question is vexing me, I must say. I half suspect an explicit description of the subnet will not be available, but rather that it must be obtained by 'Zorning'. I'm not sure though

Comment: if this is still unanswered in a few days I may bounty it

Comment: Have you shown the paper's other claim that "every filter is the derived filter of some net"? i.e. $\mathcal{G}=\mathcal{F}[w_\bullet]$ for at least one net $w_\bullet$. Modifying the proof of that may help us with the original problem

Comment: @FShrike Yes. Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a filter on $X$. Define $D:= \{(x,F)\in X\times \mathcal{F}:x\in F\}$ and $\preceq _D$ by: given any $(x,F),(y,G)\in D$, $(x,F)\preceq _D (y,G)$ iff $G\subseteq F$. Then $D$ is a direct set and $\phi :D\to X$ given by $\phi (x,F):=x$ is a net. It's easy to show that $\mathcal{G}=\mathcal{F}[\phi ]$.

Comment: I tried something similar to this but this doesn’t work if $\mathcal{G}$ contains a set with more than two elements ie $X$ is not singleton. Choose $x\neq y$ in $F\in\mathcal{G}$. Then $(x,F)\preceq(y,F)\preceq(x,F)$ but $(x,F)\neq(y,F)$. So the ordering on $D$ is not a poset ordering, just a preorder.

Comment: @FShrike The relation $\preceq$ doesn't need to be anti-symmetric! See: [Directed Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_set).

Comment: Oh seriously? That would explain a lot. I've been trying to solve this problem using a directed poset